# Is it possible to redirect TCP connection with SSL Passthrough in nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, nginx-config

With the **stream** block in nginx, TCP proxy is not available in nginx. With SSL passthrough configuration it can pass the client certificate all the way to the backend service for verification.

I want to redirect this TCP connection from nginx with all the certificates to https endpoint of same service

**Updated question: 
So request is coming for http://demo.local which need to be redirected to https://demo.local then do SSL passthrough after redirect for https request**

----> Nginx configuration

````
http {
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name demo.local;
       location / {
           return 302 https://demo.local$request_uri
       }
    }
}
stream {
# main log compatible format
    log_format stream '$remote_addr - - [$time_local] "$ssl_preread_server_name -> $name ($protocol)" '
                          '$status $bytes_sent "" "" "" ';

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
        demo.local pt-up-demo.local;
    }
    upstream pt-up-demo.local {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
    upstream proxy-up-demo.local {
        server x.x.x.x:8080;
    }
    server {
        listen 5000 proxy_protocol;
        proxy_pass proxy-up-demo.local'
    }
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $name;
        proxy_protocol on;
        ssl_preread on;
        access_log /dev/stdout stream;
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 1):

A HTTP redirect is done at the HTTP level not at the HTTPS level. In order to let nginx issue this redirect the TLS connection needs to be terminated by nginx - which conflicts with the SSL passthrough you want.

Comment: Can we do redirect at http level and then do ssl pass through?

Comment: @ChiragTayal: HTTPS is HTTP inside TLS. SSL pass through means to pass the TLS which means to pass also the encrypted HTTP inside the TLS. In other words: nginx cannot redirect at the HTTP level since it has no access to the HTTP level with SSL pass through.

Comment: can we do something like as I mentioned in next answer?

Comment: @ChiragTayal: again, this is not a configuration issue but a issue of how HTTPS works. A redirect can only be done after the TLS is terminated. With SSL pass trough TLS is not terminated by nginx and thus nginx cannot do any redirects.

Comment: I am not redirecting HTTPS request, instead HTTP request. So request is coming for `http://demo.local` which need to be redirected to `https://demo.local` then do SSL passthrough for https request

Comment: @ChiragTayal:  *"I am not redirecting HTTPS request, instead HTTP request."* - this was not clear from your question before the edit.  HTTP and HTTPS are different sections in nginx and use different ports. Therefore you can have one configuration for HTTP (port 80) which does a redirect to HTTPS and then another configuration for HTTPS (port 443) where you do SSL passthrough. Both of these configurations are not in conflict with each other since they apply to different ports.